# Getting error after renewing developer license. Can't connect to WCF service

Tags: wcf, azure, microsoft-metro, nettcpbinding, transport-security

I have a WCF *self-hosted* service, using `NetTcpBinding` with *callbacks* and *transport security* on *Windows Azure*, with a production certificate and a domain redirect.

Before renewing my developer license, everything worked. After, I'm getting this exception in the Reference.cs file:

> The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior,
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0, 
>       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension
>       'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' 
>       could not be loaded.

My colleague has yet to update her dev license, and everything still works for her.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the project and re-downloading it from source control solved the problem. No idea what happened...